# How to get the text of message, when quick reply is tapped in facebook messanger bot?

Tags: facebook, bots, webhooks, facebook-messenger, dialogflow-es

**Question related to API.AI Bot , Facebook Messanger**

When a Quick Reply is tapped, a text message will be sent to your webhook Message Received Callback. The text of the message will correspond to the title of the Quick Reply, when the content type is 'text'. How can we get the text of message! when the content type is 'location'?. It is mentioned that when we use location quick reply, we don't add title field. so how can we get a text message without using title?

I am unable to call webhook, due to not getting text of the message. 
Please help me out. I am stuck from last 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate with [ChannelData](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/core-concepts/channeldata/).

Answer (score 0):

**hehe I got your Problem** 
I hope you know the responses coming from webhook if not here is sample responses

responses for **quick_reply** with type **text**

```
"message": {
        "quick_reply": {
          "payload": "productId-12345678"
        },
        "mid": "mid.$cAAFXVKjn1KtjtBAtHFdgsrkbGWwm",
        "seq": 15453,
        "text": "buy this"
      }
```

responses for **quick_reply** with type **location**

```
"message": {
        "mid": "mid.$cAAFXVLGKMJ1jtApB51dgsTnITNet",
        "seq": 25413,
        "attachments": [
          {
            "title": "Hi-tech city Hyderabad",
            "url": "https://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bing.com%2Fmaps%2Fdefault.aspx%3Fv%3D2%26pc%3DFACEBK%26mid%3D8100%26where1%3DHyderabad%2B500081%26FORM%3DFBKPL1%26mkt%3Den-US&h=ATPXrPSDsyApPyqD9ozWt82dL9M28VZPQCqmICpsmBfXY0BCffiP4ychQ36sSWUNNBOeiJZq8tq8DLF7-A0_7VViPwwC64LM1XR-uAUN0sXdcgP5rDg&s=1&enc=AZPs1nCI5B8J4s27b7zAJKJDYaa2KSlhxQ5ppN30fb5lI3KUFcnQlSn_g4796j3p4ShwnzPvRyqXS470lEluzN06",
            "type": "location",
            "payload": {
              "coordinates": {
                "lat": 17.44521051,
                "long": 78.38363399
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
```

as you can see that in **text** type **quick_reply** we are getting the previous *context* as text to which user respond and we can use respective payload for processing. This is what facebook try to incorporate context of chat for a single time for quick reply they havnt incorporated this to other may be because of frequent use of context in case of *text* **quick_reply** rather than *location*.

Now the things which you are wondering about is *context* . Yes you need to maintain context of chat and thats how a real bot thing came into picture. you can maintain context of chat using many free nlp engine like *wit.ai , api.ai and other*